# Water body Extraction using SNAP

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I am using SAR image and SNAP tool to extract water bodies. Followed the below link ( http://www.un-spider.org/advisory-support/recommended-practices/recommended-practice-flood-mapping/step-by-step) and could extract the water bodies successfully.

However, the problem what I am facing is along with the water bodies, standing water with crop fields are also extracted.

How can that be avoided?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using Sentinel-1 data a flooded rice field is pretty much indistinguishable from any other water body.

If you want to stick to Sentinel-1 data and process it with SNAP you could exploit the fact that rice fields are only temporarily flooded.

1. create the water mask for multiple satellite images on different times of the year
2. create a stack of water masks and only keep the pixels that are masked as water in all/most images

This way you can differentiate permanent from temporary water bodies.